# How do I add images to my emails?

Tags: images

I am unable to upload images onto the server for my email newsletter. Will you please provide technical support? 
Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Jaimie - if you can flesh out a bit more so folk now what is/isn't working. Do you see a wysiwyg when creating an email, does it offer an image icon, what happens when you click on it, etc etc. The more you let other folk 'look over your shoulder' the easier it is to offer an answer. Screenshots really help too, as do links/paths so folk can try to replicate. Lastly, consider trying something on a system everyone else can look at eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org